# How to call an ASP.net Web APi with input parameters from python?

Tags: python, asp.net

I have an ASP.net API which is exposed at the below URL which takes an input parameter `softwareProductBuildID`

It is run like `http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/GetSanityResults?softwareProductBuildID=CI_MSM1234.LA.1.0.0.12-00491-INT-66`

`API URL`:http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/GetSanityResults
`INPUT PARAMETER`:softwareProductBuildID(Eg: CI_MSM1234.LA.1.0.0.12-00491-INT-66)

I googled and I was able to get to the point where I could construct something like below,it doesn't work though,My question is how to send the input parameter to the API using python?
it doesn't look like it needs an XML,how to fix this?

```
import requests
with open("HK.xml") as f:
    body = f.read()
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(
    'http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/GetSanityResults', data=body, headers=headers)

print "Printing DEV Pool Response\n"
print response
print "Done...Printing Dev Pool Response\n"

print response.ok
print response.content
```

POST API call:

```
'''
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "PropagationSIInfo": [ \ 
     { \ 
       "MainlineSI": "string", \ 
       "DerivateSI": "string" \ 
     }, \ 
     { \ 
       "MainlineSI": "string", \ 
       "DerivateSI": "string" \ 
     } \ 
   ], \ 
   "username": "string", \ 
   "IsDelete": true \ 
 }' 'http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/PropogationRules'

 '''
```

UPDATED cODE:--

```
import requests
import json
jsonData = '''{
    "PropagationSIInfo": [
        {
            "MainlineSI": "string",
            "DerivateSI": "string"
        },
        {
            "MainlineSI": "string",
            "DerivateSI": "string"
        }
    ],
    "username": "string",
    "IsDelete": True
})'''

jsonToPython = json.loads(jsonData)
response = requests.post("http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/PropogationRules", json=jsonData)

print "Printing API Response\n"
print response
print "Done...Printing API Response\n"
print response.ok
print response.content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/GetSanityResults?softwareProductBuildID=CI_MSM1234.LA.1.0.0.12-00491-INT-66` is correct, then I think you just want:

```
response = requests.get(
    "http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/GetSanityResults",
    params={
        "softwareProductBuildID": "CI_MSM1234.LA.1.0.0.12-00491-INT-66"
    }
)
```

The `params` keyword argument is how you add query parameters to a request with the `requests` library.

**EDIT**

I believe your `POST` request would look like this:

```
response = requests.post("http://company.com/api/SoftwareProduct/PropogationRules", json={
    "PropagationSIInfo": [
        {
            "MainlineSI": "string",
            "DerivateSI": "string"
        },
        {
            "MainlineSI": "string",
            "DerivateSI": "string"
        }
    ],
    "username": "string",
    "IsDelete": True
})
```

Comment: its a GET API, you are suggesting to use request.get?how to use it?

Comment: If it's a `GET`, then see my edit where I use `requests.get` instead of `requests.post`.

Comment: dont we have to use the headers field like`headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`  ?

Comment: Why? That would only make sense if you were sending JSON.

Comment: okay..is there a link I can go over what all the parameters and options available?also I believe I can send multiple parameters with comma seperated?

Comment: Did you have trouble finding the documentation for the `requests` library? What search terms did you try?

Comment: - Thanks for the info so far.. `GET` API calls are working now ,still having trouble making a POST call,I updated my question for the POST API example..how would yo send a POST API for such request in python?

Comment: ,your edit works too,is there a way to construct the json being inputed to the API on the fly using python programmatically?currently I am inputting it  manually but would like to know the options to create it dynamically

Comment: No offense, but it seems like step 1 for you should perhaps be to learn Python. :-)

Comment: I kind of updated my code with what I have changing your edit a bit but I get a compilation error at `jsonData = '{`

Comment: I fixed it ,it needs `'''` but I think the JSOn variable  in requests.post is not getting in JSOn object

Comment: Drop the `'''` on both sides.

Comment: Oh, and delete the line doing the `json.loads`.

Comment: that throws a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `})`

Comment: Delete the right paren. Again, you really need to first learn Python.